# Automating Rest API that performs a search using Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured

I a new to API testing.I am automating the Rest APIs using Rest Assured and am having a confusion in validating a get request.

The API returns a set of results as per the search parameters received from a Search UI.The URL goes as `www.xxxxxx.com/index.php?option=xxxxxx&task=xxxxxx?key1=value1?key2=value2?key3=value3..............`
There are about 20 parameters likewise in the URL.

```
BaseURI = "www.xxxxxx.com"
Response response = given().param("key1",value1).when ().get ("/index.php");
```

Is this the correct way to define the get URL or should I include all the parameters passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create request and response specs and use it in all the API tests as this way you won't have to repeat the common assertions. Also what you have is a GET API so to call it is somewhat different from your given code. Please have a look at this sample code

```
ResponseSpecBuilder builder = new ResponseSpecBuilder();
builder.expectStatusCode(200);
builder.expectContentType(ContentType.JSON);
responseSpecs = builder.build();
RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
requestSpecBuilder.setBaseUri("domainName");
requestSpecs = requestSpecBuilder.build();
given().spec(requestSpecs).
            when().get(endpoint + "?option=xxxxxx&task=xxxxxx").
            then().spec(responseSpecs).
            body("xyz", equalTo("value"));
```

In this test, we are checking that if the response code is 200, content type is JSON and in json response the "xyz" element has value "value".